# PhpStorm Deployment - asks for login credentials every time

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I setup deployment to sync my project code with the project on the FTP server where my website is stored.

However, I always have to login each time when I try to sync.
I even checked remember, but it does not work!

[image]

I am using the latest PhpStorm 2017.1.4

I tried it via sftp and ftp, the result is the same.

The Settings page for "Deployment" takes minimum 2 Minutes to load btw!

UPDATE:
I noticed that the credentials are not getting saved!
I've entered a username and password and clicked on save password, then on apply and OK. Then I close the settings menu.
If I open it again, then the fields for username and password are empty again!

[image]

Comment: Where do you store your passwords? You can check that in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords. Try switching between the native keychain and KeePass.

Comment: What do you mean? I enter it in the settings.

Comment: Click File | Settings, navigate to Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords. By default, it's set to the native keychain. Is that right for you?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. So it does only work with keepass?

Comment: I switched to KeePass and now the credentials are remembered, it seems to work now! thx! :) Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please switch to using KeePass in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords.

Generally, the Native Keychain should work too, but there might be some issues with it that need troubleshooting. If you want, submit a support ticket for PhpStorm, I'll take a look.

Comment: Now after changing to KeePass, the Deployment settings page does load instantly instead of loading at least 2 minutes btw.